# How to solve 'Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError' in console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch

This is my code to fetch API:

```
const fetchUrl = useCallback(async() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    setInfo(data.results);
    if (data.response_code === 1){
        setError(true);
    }
    setLoading(false);
}, [url]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchUrl();
}, [url, fetchUrl]);
```

It seems my code is working right but it is showing this error in console:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Can anyone see where I am wrong and how do I get rid of this warning? (My code working very well though)

Comment: Most probably you're getting HTML instead of JSON in response to your fetch. Did you try looking at the actual response?

Answer (score 0):

The error message describes that something is wrong in your JSON response.

Make sure that you are having the right JSON format and the right JSON tokens by testing your fetch response. You can try using [this](https://jsonformatter.org/) for testing the format.